# VBA code doesn't work consistantly

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to using VBA. I'm trying to wrap my head around using it correctly. I have this code and it seems to work perfectly the 1<sup>st</sup> time around but then I can't get it to work again. I'm trying to get to the match summary page for basketball games played. If I could get some assistance it would be much appreciated

```
Sub Test()
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim TDelements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim TDelement As HTMLTableCell
    Dim i As Integer

    URL = "http://www.flashscore.com/basketball/"
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .Navigate URL
        .Visible = True
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTMLdoc = .Document
    End With

    Set TDelements = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("td")
    For Each TDelement In TDelements
        If TDelement.Title = "Click for match detail!" Then
            TDelement.Click
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Please explain **how** it doesn't work consistently.

Comment: When i 1st use this code it works perfect it will bring up the match summary page but if i try to run the code again no match summary page appears.

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
Dim IE as Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

--corrected

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually looks fine with one small tweak- make sure to add:

```
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Otherwise multiple IE instances would be hiding in the background- others have suggested using CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") but I much prefer using the methodology you used so you have a true InternetExplorer object that you can see its methods & properties if necessary..

I ran it and didn't get an errors, but also didn't get any TDs to meet the If clause- this could just be due to the timing of the website and its data, element.title is not an attribute I have seen used very often so perhaps this is the source of your issues and you should revisit what attribute you are checking to meet your if clause.

Hope this helps,
ThesilkCode